# Competitive Programming Vimrc is too long

Tags: vimrc, filetype-c++

I am preparing for the Egyptian Olympiad in Informatics and I prefer vim to be my code editor, but my problem is my `vimrc`, I think it is a bit long to type at the beginning of an onsite competition, but really is it? Here it is.

```
set nocp

syntax on
colo torte

set rnu nu nowrap
set hi=1000
set cb=unnamed

set si
set ts=4
set sts=4
set sw=4
set sr

set is hls
nnoremap <CR> :noh<CR><CR>

inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<C-o>O
map <F7> :w<cr>:!g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror % -o %<<CR>
map <F8> :w<cr>:!g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror % -o %< && %<<CR>
map <F9> :w<cr>:!g++ % -o %< && %<<CR>
```

I really don't mind forgetting to write any one of the above lines (except the last four), it won't be a very big deal, but when I look at each line, they all look well worth the time needed to write them.

Should I memorize my `vimrc` as it is, or are there any changes you think I should do?

Comment: At least some programming competitions don't require such memorization.  http://contest.usc.edu/index.php/Main/Rules is an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first line really should be `runtime defaults.vim`. This is a standard file and it must be present in all Vim installations. Among other things, it saves from typing

```
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set hi=200
set is
```

Also `set cb=unnamed` is evil (just prepend `"+` before normal mode command when needed) and `set hls` IMO is more harmful (every time doing `:noh`) than useful. `set si` is no-op for C/C++ sources if you have `ftplugin` enabled.

Build with `:make` command, use `set aw` to save on make automatically.

So something like this looks shorter and still functional to me:

```
runtime defaults.vim
colo torte
set aw nu rnu nowrap
set et sr sts=-1 sw=4
nn <f7> :make CXXFLAGS="-Wall -Wextra" %:r<CR>
```

Answer (score 10):

`set nocp` is not actually needed if your vimrc is located at `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/vimrc`.

Many of your commands can be abbreviated even further

```
sy on
colo torte

se rnu nu nowrap hi=1000 cb=unnamed si ts=4 sts=4 sw=4 sr is hls

nn <CR> :noh<CR><CR>
ino {<CR> {<CR>}<C-o>O
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few interresting things already in the default C and C++ filetype plugins ->  `filetype plugin indent on`. This should enable smart indenting. No need anymore to use tabs, which could be left to the universal default of 8 -- I never use `tab` but always let Vim handle automatically the indent.

Regarding compilation, `:make %<<cr>` is enough -- Just set `$CXXFLAGS` once. Beside, this would fill the quickfix windows. In C++, this could really make the difference when dealing with ambiguities or failure to find the right overload.

```
let $CXXFLAGS = '-std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -Werror'
nnoremap <silent> <f7>   :<c-u>w<cr>:make %<<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <c-f5> :<c-u>vert term ./%<<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <f11>  :<c-u>cprev<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <f12>  :<c-u>cnext<cr>
```

Comment: Great recommendations! I think you mean `filetype plugin on`. And for automatic indentation I think you also need `filetype plugin indent on`. Good call on using `:make`, that's really the way to go.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks @filbranden, I've written it from memory. I'll fix my answer.